# How can I find the defined type of a property/field at runtime in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, reflection, properties

I am trying to get the type of a property/field in TypeScript. Specifically, from the property decorator. The property does not have a value set so I can not derive it from the type of the value. Consider an example

```
class Example {
  abc: ABC
}
```

How would I get the class/class name of the property? To be specific, not the JavaScript 'primitive' type given by `typeof x` but the actual class(name), in this case `ABC`.

I've tried using `reflect-metadata` but it doesn't look like it's retaining the defined type in the metadata, running the following code:

```
console.log(Reflect.getMetadataKeys(target) + ", " + Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, propertyKey)

// -> ", undefined"
```

So it doesn't seem like there is any metadata relating to the type defined, or at all for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one of the more advanced reflection tools.
Here they are listed (mostly): https://github.com/akutruff/typescript-needs-types

I'm an author of the [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/tst-reflect).
Here is a StackBlitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tst-reflect-example?file=index.ts) listing all properties and methods of classes and interfaces.

Sample code for your use-case:

```js
import { getType, Type } from 'tst-reflect';

interface SomeInterface {
    someProp: number;
}

class SomeClass {
    prop: SomeInterface;
}

const classType: Type = getType<SomeClass>();
console.log(classType.getProperties().map(p => p.type.name)); // [ SomeInterface ]
```